# Upload A file to a ASP.NET WebService

Tags: asp.net, web-services

To send a File in AJAX request i used the way mentioned [here](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) . How do i write the WebMethod to accept the file?

Answer (score 0):

The post & link provided gives a number of key points, please find them below:

- The action being done is a post
- The format of the object being sent is json
- As your tag's are .net & web-services, you are interested in a solution on Microsoft Stack.
- You use the term WebMethod, so you do not want to do this transaction via web api or WCF

See [link](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx) for details for "Send and Receive JSON objects to Web Service Methods using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net"